# How to connect two pc's for variable transfer using QBASIC

Tags: qbasic, qb64

Does anyone know/have the code for connecting two pc's for variable transfer in qbasic? Using the _OPENHOST , _OPENCLIENT , and _OPENCONNECTION.

Comment: There is no such functionality in Qbasic

Comment: There is but I dont know how it is used

Comment: There is in QB64 at http://www.qb64.org/wiki/OPENHOST but I don't know how it is used.

Comment: QB64 is QB64 and not QBasic @eoredson

Comment: The tags to the OP state [qb64], and there are no _OPEN functions in Qbasic to my knowledge.

Comment: Then title and question should be corrected